# Error when using Realm in React Native app with Swift view controller

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, realm

I have React Native app which is using Realm. After I added extern framework to my Xcode project through CocoaPods (there are Realm.framework and RealmSwift.framework in CocoaPods dependencies) and added ability to open Swift view controller from my app I started to get one of these errors:

["Detach accessor" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xl78.png)

or

[Xcode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCxk0.png)

Seems like Realm from React Native code conflicts with Swift Realm in extern framework. Is it possible to solve this problem or I have to use another database library in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using both realm react-native and realm-cocoa together is not officially supported. It does work though as long as the version of the two libraries you are using are using the same core version. To do this you may need to build each library from source, or figure out which version are compatible and be sure to use those.